# TinyMCE not working on Mac OS Lion

Tags: tinymce, osx-lion

I recently switched from TinyMCE 3.2.7 to 3.4.7 but one of our users has some issues. He's the only one running Mac OS Lion and he doesn't see the editor at all; all other people (running Linux, Windows, Mac OS Leopard) are seeing it. He's cleared his caches and tried multiple browsers, he even tried running Windows via Parallels but no luck. Any guesses?

Thanks,
Robbert

Comment: this seems to be an issue you should address to the tinymce developers (moxiecode). eigther file a bug report or post this in the tinymce forum: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/